# While using scons with c code on cygwin gcc, object has no attribute 'program'

Tags: gcc, scons

From below SContruct file while executing with Scons 2.5, below error is shown:
$ /cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/scons.bat
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Windows

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers
t likely not set correctly
File "C:\cygwin\lib\python2.5\scons-2.5.1\SConstruct", line 18, in 
AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'program':
  File "C:\cygwin\lib\python2.5\scons-2.5.1\SConstruct", line 19:
    env.program('mee.c')

SConstruct has:

```
    `import os
     import platform
     print platform.system()
     DefaultEnvironment(tools = [])
     env = DefaultEnvironment()
     print env
     env = Environment(tools = ['default', 'gcc'])
     env.program('mee.c')
     `
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct, there is no method named `program()` available for a build environment. Try

```
env.Program(...)
```

instead (note the capital P) and also consult our [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), please.